# How to decide the resonant frequency

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, electromagnetism, resonance

I have a circuit of the following form.

Circuit diagram:

[image]

How do I decide the resonant frequency ?

What is the criteria here to select the resonant frequency ?

Background: I am testing the transfer function for the system, and I need to know what is the proper value of "w" (omega) I can use.

Please let me know if anyone has the knowledge on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have spice make you a bode plot?  Run a signal generator into the input and measure the output as a function of frequency.   I trust the inductors aren't coupled.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold...Please let me know how did you think it is not coupled. I want to know. Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First find the equivalent impedance of your circuit using, e.g., Thevenin theorem.  This impedance will depend on \$\omega\$.  The resonant frequency(ies) is(are) the value(s) of \$\omega\$ that makes the reactive part of the impedance zero.

Comment: Is there any tool which does the calculation of thevenin equivalent voltage and imedance  of the circuit?..I really can't believe my calculations, so I am keep looking for some verification methods.

Comment: I use a computer algebra system to help doing the calculations.  In my case, it's maxima, but I think Mathematica and even Matlab also do the same thing.  Basically I write the impedance for each element and combine them manually in series or parallel.  Although it's not automated it does help a lot in the calculations.  For example, for your example, it took me less than 5 mins to find that the resonant frequencies are \$\omega=0\$ and \$\omega=1/C_1(L_1+L_3)\$.

Comment: The full denominator of the Thevenin impedance is \$j\omega^2C_1C_2R_1 + \omega C_2\(1 -\omega^2C_1(L_1 + L_3))\$.

Comment: Please scrape off the \$\omega=0\$ resonant frequency.  \$\omega=0\$ actually zeroes the full denominator, which means the impedance is infinite and the load will not get anything.

Comment: OK, hold on because in my hurry I forgot \$R_L\$.

Comment: The \$R_L\$ term does make the answer longer, although using a computer algebra system helps a lot.  I'm gonna write down the resonant frequency only: $$\omega = \sqrt{(R_L+R_2)/C_1+R_1/C_2}/\sqrt{(L_3+L_1)(R_L+R_2)+L_2R_1}.$$ Note two things: (1) when \$R_L\rightarrow \infty\$ we get the answer above; (2) Since a finite \$R_L\$ makes current pass through \$R_2\$, \$C_2\$ and \$L_2\$, the resonant frequency depends also on these terms.